# $compile is not defined in angular controller

Tags: angularjs

Im trying to clone a div tag which contains few HTML elements with ng-click function,

But dynamically cloned and appended HTML elements not firing ng-click function,

Can anyone help me out

this is the code i used

```
angular.module('AddNewCab', [])

  .controller('cabcontainer', ['$scope','$compile', function($scope,$compile) {

    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.myFunc = function($compile) {
        $scope.count=$scope.count+1;
       var source = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#cabdata' ));
       var container = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#cabcontainer' ));
       var uniqueid='cabdata'+$scope.count;
       var temp=$compile(source.clone().attr('id',uniqueid),$scope);
       container.append(temp);
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: You don't need to inject `[]` inside your app module if you are defining a controller or any other kind of module. Remove it: `angular.module('AddNewCab').controller...` .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't how your HTML file is but I created one example of this.

Take a peek: [https://plnkr.co/edit/ZQ7EYw5CB3DojCKs7Qlv](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZQ7EYw5CB3DojCKs7Qlv?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="cabcontainer">
  <div id="cabdata">
    <p>Test1</p>
    <p>Test2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="cabcontainer">
    <p>Clone here</p>
  </div>
  <input type="button" ng-click="myFunc()" value="Clone"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('AddNewCab', [])

  .controller('cabcontainer', ['$scope','$compile', function($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.myFunc = function() {

       $scope.count=$scope.count+1;
       var source = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#cabdata' ));
       var container = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#cabcontainer' ));

       var uniqueid='cabdata'+$scope.count;
       var temp= $compile(source.clone().attr('id',uniqueid))($scope);
       container.append(temp);
    };
  }]);
```

Note: I made some changes in your controller, for example, there is no need to put the $compile in you function because it's already injected on the controller by angular.

Comment: Thanks Joel, im trying a similar functionality but this clone button have to duplicate on every clone,

Comment: Np @ravi, let me understand, do wanna clone the button too?

Comment: Yes Joel, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If i do understand you right, you want to add an eventlistener to dynamically created elements? in that case i would use jQuery instead of ng-click. Someting like

```
$("parentElement").on("click", "elementToClick", function() {
   //your code here
});
```

You could do the same with an angular directive, but jQuery was easier to explain.
And if you need parameters, you can add them with data-attributes to the element and call them with

```
this.getAttribute("data-AttributeName")
```

Oh, and if you use ng-attributes, make them to data-ng-* (e.g. data-ng-click). Will bring no chances to functionality, but make your code html valid.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, actually im trying to clone a div tag and append to another div, container.append(source.clone().attr('id',uniqueid)); this source contains one ng-click function (Similar to add new row icon). Newly created rows ng-click is not firing, event listners too not firing from newly created code,

Comment: don't recommend people use a different framework because its "easier to explain"...

Comment: In that case my answer is really right i dare to say. Perhaps i should explain it a bit more: 
$("parentElement").on("click", "elementToClick", function() {});

parentElement is the element the eventlistener is bound to. Use a element that always there. If no one else there, just use body. "elementToClick" is the element, where the eventlistener is reacting to.

So, if i write $("body").on("click", ".button", function() {alert("Hello world"); }); there will be always an alert if you click on an element with the class "button". But the eventlistener itself is on body.

Comment: @Claies Most people do not know that angular is build on jquery. if you use angular without jquery, angular.element is an alias for a jquery light version. if you bind in jquery before angular, angular.element is an alias for jquery itself. so, not really a different framework.

Comment: Using jquery, you are disconnecting your UI from your model, and anything you do inside that function angular won't know about and won't be able to respond to.  Just because angular uses jQuery to do some things internally doesn't mean that using jQuery instead of angular when things aren't working right is a good thing.